# Custom posts per page does not work with pagination

Tags: query-posts, pagination, paged

I have one page in my template where I would like to set a custom posts_per_page.
Here is the code I have used:

```
<?php
global $query_string;
query_posts($query_string . '&posts_per_page=4'); 
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
...
```

Now this code limits only 4 items per page and shows pageinate_links below as I have written. However clicking on any other page will lead to a 404.

If I take out the global and query_posts line then it works fine.

This is the paginate_links function I am using:

```
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text' => 'Previous',
    'next_text' => 'Next',  
) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action in your `functions.php` with [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), and remove the call to `query_posts`:

```
function wpa62751_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_category( 'my-category' ) && is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 4 );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa62751_pre_get_posts' );
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Note -** The recommended way is pointed out by @Milo, Use of `pre_get_post` is always a good choice over `query_posts`

However, you can make it work with pagination by passing `paged` parameter.

**Example -**

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( 
                $wp_query->query, // old query
                array( 
                    'posts_per_page' => 4,
                    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
                    //  'paged' => get_query_var('page')
                ) 
        );  
query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, however I still recieve page 404 on any other page other than the first page.

Why would using `pre_get_post` be better than `query_posts`?

Comment: @Imran See [These](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/17968),[Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/17968)